# How to use RTK Query properly when I have different basequeries? Ex. axiosBaseQuery and graphqlBaseQuery

Tags: react-native, graphql, rtk-query

My understanding is there should only be one createapi in your app. How would I use two basequeries in RTK query?

Ex. **createApi with axiosBaseQuery**

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
 reducerPath: "apiSlice",
 baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery,
 endpoints: (builder) => ({
   fetchSomething: builder.query<Resource, string>({
     query: (resourceUUID) => ({
       url: `/services/buresource/collections/${resourceUUID}?component_level=1`,
       method: "get",
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Ex. **createapi with graphql basequery**

```
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: graphqlBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://graphqlzero.almansi.me/api',
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPosts: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        body: gql`
          query {
            posts {
              data {
                id
                title
              }
            }
          }
        `,
      }),
      transformResponse: (response) => response.posts.data,
    }),
  }),
})
```

I'm pretty new to rtk-query and react native in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really talking to different apis (and I imagine it couldnt' get more different if one uses graphql and the other REST), it is also okay to have multiple createApis. You just shouldn't do that for one interconnected dataset.

Just make sure to set the `reducerPath` option to `createApi` when creating those.